# Riemann series theorem wikipedia example problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the wikipedia article of Riemann series theorem , they give us an example of Riemann series theorem by calculating the alternated harmonic sum that converge to ln(2). And they show that by rearranging the sum one obtains ln(2)/2. However if you get a close look at the method described, you will see that for every next inverse odd term they assign it the two next inverse even term :

```
impair -------  the two next pair
1/1               -1/2-1/4   =  1/2*(1-1/2)
1/3                -1/6-1/8 = 1/2*(1/3-1/4)
1/5                -1/10-1/12 = 1/2*(1/5-1/6)
1/7                 ........

for finally get 1/2(1-1/2+1/3-1/4+....) = ln(2)/2
```

THE PROBLEM comes because the rearranging is not complete, in the sense that for each inverse odd we need two inverse even, so that if we were to compute the sum from i=0 to p really big, we would have to ignore the odd numbers greater than p/2. I think that the example of wikipedia is more a proof that lim p to infinity of the alternated harmonic sum and we ignore inverse impair greater than p/2 tends to ln(2)/2. With a C program you can verify experimentally that it is true. So it is not the same sum, so the rearranging terminology seems unappropriated. Does anyone agree with me ?

Below is the C program computing the series where you ignore odds greater than p/2 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

    int minus1pow(int n)
{
    n%=2;
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int p;
    printf("\nEnter large integer\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    int i;
    double r=0;
    for(i=1;i<p;i++)
        if(!(i>p/2&&i%2))
            r+=minus1pow(i+1)/(i+0.0);

    printf("Result is : %.13f, Ln(2)/2 is : %.13f\n\n\n",r,log(2)/2);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This site uses $\LaTeX$: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  In other words, try and put dollar signs around the math please.

Comment: why can't I ask my question in the exact form of how I wrote it. I don't need latex, html for this, I just want to post simple ascii

Comment: @AndreMiville rolled back to try to format your code and ascii table. The question is still unclear - do you mean "odd" and "even" when you say ""impair" and "pair"?

Comment: wow how did you did that ? I want to be able to do the same

Comment: Text indented four spaces will not be interpreted and display as written. There is a button on the edit bar like this: `{}` which will indent the selected text.